# my program does not end for loop properly

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying the **"fizz buzz"** problem with ArrayList. My program runs fine and executes as intended till n-th iteration. Suppose entering value `100`. "fizz buzz" gets executed till 100 and returns result, but it is doing extra iteration and adding value to `ArrayList<String> numfb`

for `n=100` extra 20 iterations
for `n=50` extra 10 iterations

As I understand for loop should end after `i<n` which are number of iteration and values added to array list.

Here is my code:

```
int i , n;
String temp;
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
ArrayList<Integer> number=new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> numfb=new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println("enter array range");
n=input.nextInt();
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
  number.add(i,i+1);
}
for(i=0; i<n ;i++){
  if(!( (number.get(i)) % 3==0) || ( (number.get(i)) % 5==0) ){
    temp=String.valueOf(number.get(i));
    numfb.add(i,temp);
  }
  if( (number.get(i)) % 5==0 && (number.get(i)) % 3==0 ){
    numfb.add(i,"FizzBuzz");
  }
  else if( (number.get(i) ) %3 == 0){
    numfb.add(i,"Fizz");
  }
  else if( (number.get(i) ) % 5 == 0 ){
    numfb.add(i,"Buzz");
  }
}
System.out.println(number);
System.out.println(numfb);
```

Comment: you are missing an else if on the second condition in your loop

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `list.add(index, item)` if you want to add item at end of list. Simply use `list.add(item)`.

Comment: Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an else if you on your second condition in your loop

```
if(!( (number.get(i)) % 3==0) || ( (number.get(i)) % 5==0) ){
    temp=String.valueOf(number.get(i));
    numfb.add(i,temp);
  }
  else if( (number.get(i)) % 5==0 && (number.get(i)) % 3==0 ){
    numfb.add(i,"FizzBuzz");
  }
  else if( (number.get(i) ) %3 == 0){
    numfb.add(i,"Fizz");
  }
  else if( (number.get(i) ) % 5 == 0 ){
    numfb.add(i,"Buzz");
  }
```

Comment: Thanx it helped